# T-Test in R using "ggpubr"

Tags: r, statistics, ggpubr

I am trying to perform a two sided t-test with R.

This is my data as CSV (called "laegern" in the code):

```
coverage;type;P
grassland;litter;0.0965
grassland;topsoil;0.0762
grassland;subsoil;0.071
grassland;litter;0.0973
grassland;topsoil;0.0626
grassland;subsoil;0.0541
grassland;litter;0.0769
grassland;topsoil;0.0558
grassland;subsoil;0.0584
forest;litter;0.0749
forest;topsoil;0.0519
forest;subsoil;0.0315
forest;litter;0.0637
forest;topsoil;0.0445
forest;subsoil;0.0412
forest;litter;0.0769
forest;topsoil;0.0482
forest;subsoil;0.042
```

And this my code:

```
library(ggpubr)
....
t.test(laegern$P~laegern$type =="litter", var.equal = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")
```

Everything from importing, plotting etc. is working, but the code for the statistical test does not take the right values.
The aim is to make a t-test for the value "P" with "litter" comparing "grassland" and "forest". The same should as well be done for the "topsoil" and "subsoil".
Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot a nice evening.

Comment: Welcome to SO! this t.test functions is from the `stats` package, and not ggpubr

Comment: Does `laegern$P[laegern$type == "litter"] ~ laegern$coverage[laegern$type == "litter"]` do what you want?

Comment: I don't know if **ggpubr** changes `t.test()`, but for `stats::t.test()` I would probably do something like `t.test(P ~ coverage, data = laegern, subset = type =="litter", var.equal = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")`.  See the documentation at `?t.test.formula` for some of the argument definitions.

Comment: @aosmith I think it's unlikely  - on a quick glance in the exported namespace of ggpubr, I did not find a method for stats::t.test

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast respond. "A. S. K." it worked with your attempt and as well with that of "aosmith". The difference is that with the first attempt you are doing a "Welch's t-test" which is for unequal variances and with the second you're doing a "Two Sample t-test" for equal variances.  
Thanks again and a nice day.